# Cannot find parent: net.java:jvnet-parent for project: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9

Tags: maven, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

My project invloves of spring-data-neo4j,when runnging mvn clean install,
there is a maven build error.

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9

Reason: Cannot find parent: net.java:jvnet-parent for project: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9 for project com.sun.jersey:jersey-project:pom:1.9
```

Comment: Got a sample project to test out?

Comment: did you end up solving this ? if so would you kindly share how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 8):

"The root cause is a deficiency in Maven 2.2.1. It's not following 301 redirects; if you look at the .pom that is downloaded into your local repository, you will see the 301 HTML that was delivered from the server. More information is available at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WAGON-314 . It sounds like the only workaround is to either downgrade to 2.2.0, or upgrade to a newer version of Maven 3." (mrandall_cerner_com at https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1080 )

Answer (score 8):

I second the issue here with specific version of maven installation. 2.2.1

Steps for resolution : (Assuming you have ubuntu)

If maven (2.2.1) is already installed :

```
  sudo apt-get remove maven2 [To uninstall current maven 2.2.1]
  sudo apt-get install maven [Will install upgraded version]
```

Verify :

```
   mvn --version [Expect to display 3.*]
```

Comment: Balaji, I love you! You've just saved my day!

Comment: Romeo, I am glad it helped :) Its all about sharing !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see:

Go to Eclipse-> Window-> Preferences->Maven->User Settings

Copy the local repository path of your machine

Navigate to .m2\repository\com\sun\jersey\jersey-project and clean all folders
if jersey-project folder is not there then
clean .m2\repository\com\sun\jersey contents..

Then on you project update you maven depencies (then check if all jars are downloaded to .m2\repository\com\sun\jersey folder)